# How to use GitHub primer with GitHub pages

Tags: sass, github-pages

I am trying to use https://github.com/primer/css within GitHub pages.

There are some npm commands but I don't know how to import the files to my project folder.

Adding `@import "@primer/css/index.scss";` to my style.css file is not sufficient. I need some sass files but I don't know where to find them after running `npm install --save @primer/css`. I know that the answer is easy and I read about the `--prefix` option.

I am sure I am missing something trivial but important. Give me a hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the CDN mentioned in the [primer documentation](https://primer.style/css/getting-started#using-primer-css-on-a-static-site) worked for me:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@primer/css@^20.2.4/dist/primer.css" />`

The layout file imports the main.scss file:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">`

The main.scss file imports the required file:

`@import url(https://unpkg.com/@primer/css@^20.2.4/dist/primer.css);`